# German characters en-/decoding issue

Tags: oracle, perl, encoding

I have a perl script. The simplified version looks like this:

```
my $sel = "SELECT DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL($type,  '$name', '$owner')  FROM DUAL";
my $sth = $dbh->prepare( $sel ) or die "Can't prepare statement: $DBI::errstr";
my $rc = $sth->execute  or die "Can't execute statement: $DBI::errstr";
my $code = $sth->fetchrow();   
$sql = "INSERT INTO  MY_TABLE (CODE) VALUES (?)";
$stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute($code);
```

So, the script simpy get a CLOB text, save it in a `$code` variable and insert it to a table.

The command `SELECT * FROM NLS_DATABASE_PARAMETERS WHERE PARAMETER = 'NLS_CHARACTERSET';` returns `WE8MSWIN1252`.
My problem is, that in the $code variable occur German characters. After executing the INSERT to DB the encoding is wrong. The geman special characters(umlauts) are displayed not correctly. `guess_encoding($code);` returns `Encode::XS=SCALAR(0x...)`.
How can I decode and encode the `$code` variable in a proper way? How can I check what the `guess_encoding` returns? As already mentioned, the '`CODE`' field is of type `CLOB`.

Comment: I once had a similar issue and fixed it by passing the desired  nls/encoding settings client-side for my connection while getting the connection itself `my $dbh = DBI->connect ([ADDITIONAL OPTIONS HERE])`.  Just a hint, can't find the example anymore :/

Comment: I think you need appropriate environment variables like `NLS_LANG=American_America.AL32UTF8`. You can also set this variable in BEGIN block. See also [DBD::Oracle document](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBD::Oracle#Oracle-and-Unicode)

Comment: Three potential issues: 1) The character set of the db fields, 2) the character set used to communicate, and 3) the encoding of the Perl string. /// Re 1: I think you're saying the fields use cp1252. I don't know German, but I think cp1252 is enough to for German. /// Re 2: One normally communicates using UTF-8. With DBD::Oracle, this appears to be done by passing `ora_charset => 'AL32UTF8'` to `connect`. /// Re 3: The encoding of the Perl string probably needs to match what DBD::Oracle uses to communicate.